# Unusual Performance Setting Integer Array Values

Tags: java, arrays, performance

This is a strange case that recently came up while profiling a specialised collection I've been working on.

The collection is pretty much just two arrays, one an `int[]` array of keys, and one an `Object[]` array of values, with a hash function providing rapid lookup. It's all working nicely, but I've come to profiling the code and am getting some weird results; for profiling I've decided to do it the old fashioned way, by grabbing `System.currentTimeMillis()`, running a test over and over and then checking how much time has elapsed, like so:

```
long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int index : indices) 
    foo.remove(index);
long took = System.currentTimeMillis() - sTime;
```

In my test I have `foo` prepared with 200,000 entries, and a pre-generated the list of `indices` that I will remove. I reset and run the test using a loop for a thousand repetitions and add `took` to a running total.

Now, for commands I get extremely good results compared to other data types, except with my `remove(int)` method. However, I've been struggling to figure out why, as my removal method is identical to my `get(int)` method (other than the removal obviously), as shown:

```
public Object get(int key) {
    int i = getIndex(key); // Hashes key and locates it
    return (i >= 0) ? this.values[i] : null;
}

public Object remove(int key) {
    int i = getIndex(key); // Does exactly the same as above
    if (i >= 0) {
        --this.size;
        ++this.modifications; // For concurrent access behaviour

        this.keys[i] = 0; // Zero indicates null entry
        Object old = this.values[i];
        this.values[i] = null;
        return old;
    }
    return null;
}
```

While I would expect the removal to take a bit longer, they're taking more than 5 times as long to execute as `get(int)`. However, if I comment out the line `this.keys[i] = 0` then performance becomes nearly identical to `get(int)`.

Am I correct in observing that this is an issue with assigning a value to my `int[]` array? I've tried commenting out all the `this.values` operations and experience the same slow times, but leaving `this.values` while commenting out `this.keys[i] = 0` consistently solves the problem; I'm at a total loss as to what's going on, is there anything to be done about it?

The performance is still good considering that removals are relatively rare, but it seems strange that setting a value in an `int[]` is seemingly having such a big impact, so I'm curious to know why.

Comment: I think you need to give a fully reproducible benchmark, preferably leveraging a benchmark library like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) to eliminate the most common pitfalls.

Comment: A random guess: when you zero `keys[]` elements, `getIndex()` has more work to do when looking for a key. Anyway, please provide more context - the problem could be either in your benchmark or in `getIndex()` or any other place not shown to us.

Comment: Well I was hoping to avoid having to post too much more; my test is setup such that `remove(int)` is only called for keys that are known to exist, and `getIndex(int)` returns in constant time. Besides, I'm certain it's not `getIndex(int)` that's at fault, as commenting out `this.keys[i] = 0` changes the results dramatically (1200ms to 200ms, same as `get(int)`), I just can't understand why.

Comment: I've tried creating a JBenchX test case and have run it several times with and without `this.keys[i] = 0` and am getting similar results. Tests with the statement enabled come in around 214ns, while tests without are 56ns. When disabling `this.keys[i] = 0` I'm replacing it with `this.values[i] = DELETED` (marker object) and the corresponding checks, yet somehow it's nearly four times faster.

Comment: Look for the pieces of code where `keys[]` is read. Seems like zeroing changes the execution path. Try also running JVM with `-Xint` option to exclude JIT optimization factor. Will `remove` be still 5x slower?

Comment: When I comment out `this.key[i] = 0` I also change to `this.values[i] = DELETED` (special object) and change my checks to also test for that, i.e - a check for `this.key[i] != 0` becomes `(this.key[i] != 0) && (this.values[i] != DELETED)`, so none of the logic is changing, yet somehow the more complex tests are more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

The code as written doesn't work concurrently. If there's other concurrency code not shown, that could well be the source timing differences. Other than that, the most likely cause is merely accessing the keys[] array in addition to the values[] array changes memory access patterns. For instance, switching from registers to memory locations, L1 cache to L2 cache, or L3 cache, or main memory. 'False sharing' is an example of a degradation pattern. 'Mechanical sympathy' is a name used for tuning to current hardware architectures.

Comment: It's not a thread-safe class, the `modifications` variable is used to throw `ConcurrentModificationException` from my `Iterator` in case concurrent access is occurring. I wasn't going to bother leaving it in the code snippet but felt I should in case it could somehow be part of the problem.

Comment: Use a profiler. The issue is likely in a part of the code you haven't posted.